# Java server socket: Connection refused

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have a Windows server on which I have a server socket that listens on port 18451:

```
D:>netstat -a | findstr 18451
  TCP    0.0.0.0:18451          XW10LSCP0030:0         LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:18451             XW10LSCP0030:0         LISTENING
```

On the same server I have a client program that tries to connect to this server socket:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(inetSocketAddress.getAddress(), inetSocketAddress.getPort());
```

However I get a connection refused connection:

```
localhost/127.0.0.1:18451: Connection refused: connect
```

The windows firewall is not running. How can this be explained ?

Comment: how are you doing the connection? It sounds to me it should be or localhost:18451 or 127.0.0.1:18451, but not both together localhost/127.0.0.1:18451

Comment: the connection is done to localhost

Comment: Can you and the code?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: can you telnet on that port ??

Comment: no, same issue, connection refused

Comment: The server is clearly in a listening state, but it is likely not accepting new clients in a timely manner, if at all. Its backlog has likely filled up.